# Is it possible for an element with position: fixed have the width of 100?

Tags: css

So, is it possible for an element with position: fixed have the width of 100? :D

I've tried with absolute, and its working. But what about fixed?

Also - is it possible to have a larger font size?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Learn to frame your questions properly though. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It might look something like this:

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#text {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>Just use "width: 100px;"</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<span id="text">This is how you change the font-size: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp">https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp</a></span>
```

Maybe you forgot 'px?'

Comment: Let me know if this helped you out, and if it did please accept it as best answer.